# onListViewItemClick View argument refer to multiple listitems

Tags: android, listview

In onListItemClick I want to change clicked item background, this is my code:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){

    if (position != previous_position){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_clicked_item_bg);
        if (previous_category != null)
            previous_category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_item_bg);
        previous_category = v;
        previous_position = position;
    }
}
```

previous_category and previous_position are protected variables.

The problem is, that on item click multiple items in list are highlighted (more specifically 1 or 2). In list there are 20 rows, if I click one in middle, only one gets highlighted, if I click any row in beginning or end, other row in opposite side gets highlighted with interval 13 rows (that's probably the reason why pressing middle row don't highlight second).

I need list to highlight only one row the clicked one, what is the problem?

**ADDITIONAL CODE**

If that can help, here is also ListView adapter class:

```
package domehotel.guestbook.page.category;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import domehotel.guestbook.R;

public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoryItem>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
CategoryItem data[] = null;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CategoryItem[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    CategoryHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new CategoryHolder();
        holder.category_name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CategoryHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    CategoryItem category = data[position];
    holder.category_name.setText(category.category_name);

    return row;
}

static class CategoryHolder
{
    TextView category_name;
}
}
```

Comment: are you using view holder in your adapter? which supplies views to the listview

Comment: @Android_Crazy I added ListView adapter class code also. If you mean am I holding row views in adapter, then no, or am I wrong? (I'm a bit inexperienced in android and java).

Comment: @Janis from your code it is clear that you are reusing the convertView. basically the issue is once you set the background of the view v in onListItemClick the same view v is populated with different data(i.e category.category_name) and shown on the screen hence you are getting more than one view have background set to image category_clicked_item_bg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you are reusing views. getView takes as 2nd parameter a View named convertView. The ListView calls this method with an old View item (if there is one), which is instantiated (inflated) but not displayed at the moment. Your meth. onListItemClick now sets the backround of one of these Views, but this View will be reused later for another row, without resetting it's backround.

A possible soloution:

1. The click listener should only store the background color, or a clicked flag, for a clicked position somewhere and then ask the View (row) in question to rerender (it could also save state and then set the background directly).
2. The getView(..) method should *always* set the background color of a View according to the saved color/state for its position. Set a normal background for positions not marked as clicked or set another background for positions marked as clicked by the click listener.

Comment: This answer made me to understand why this is happening, but solution is not correct, this solution would lead to case where active row slides out from visible part, gets redrawn and changes its background to not active state.

Comment: "gets redrawn and changes its background to not active state" - That's right. One conclusion could be: set background in your click listener once, save the state (position -> bg color) and set it in getView(..) ALWAYS according to saved state (position -> bg color).

Answer (score 1):

Since the ListView row View objects are reused each for multiple rows its not good idea to keep information about which row is active in row View, better idea is to keep this information in Adapter (in my case CategoryAdapter). data Array of type CategoryItem keeps objects of following class:

```
public class CategoryItem {

    public String category_name;
    public Boolean is_active = false;

    public CategoryItem(){
        super();
    }

    public CategoryItem(String category_name){
        super();
        this.category_name = category_name.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

And adapter, when redrawing an view item in onView method, checks if current row is active:

```
if (category.is_active)
    row.setBackgroundResource(activeBgDrawable);
else
    row.setBackgroundResource(inactiveBgDrawable);
```

So, when I click an item, I set CategoryItem is_active property to true and previous clicked  is_active property to false:

```
if (position != previous_position){
    CategoryAdapter adapter = (CategoryAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
    CategoryItem current_item = adapter.getItem(position);
    current_item.is_active = true;
    if (previous_position != -1){
        CategoryItem previous_item = adapter.getItem(previous_position);
                    previous_item.is_active = false;
        }
    previous_position = position;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Why setting the View objects background dont work? If I have ListView which contains ListView items more than the ListView can show, list will become scrollable and, for example, if I scroll ListView down, then when the upper item will slide out of visible part, the ListView item View object of this row will be reused for the next row which will appear at bottom. So, if the upper row would be the one whose View object background I would have changed then the when It would disappear the bottom row would be redrawn with upper ones View object with its background and thats why I some times had two colored rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in OnItemClick

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){

if (position != previous_position){
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_clicked_item_bg);   
    Object view = parent.getTag();
    if(view!=null){
       // typecasting the Object to View
       ((View)view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_item_bg);
    }
    previous_position = position;
    parent.setTag(v);
}
}
```

I Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This solution throws NullPointerException for getChildAt, i also put if condition before "parent.getChildAt" statement, so that the first click wouldn't try to unselect not existing row,

Comment: Again two rows colored, I think I understood the problem - View objects are reused, that means, when one disappears from visible part, that object is reused for next visible row (if upper one disappears then the bottom one will show up with colored background and the other way, because it is the same View object.). Probably the same what you said.

Comment: add the below mentioned code in your getView method of adapter
row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_item_bg);

Comment: tried this one before. But when the onView is called to redraw element the clicked background is changed to not clicked one due to this. I`m thinking that I should set in adapter the clicked views item variable is_active (added this one to CategoryItem) to true and in onView if category.is_active == true then set category_clicked_item_bg background, else category_item_bg. Can I change clicked rows data object (CategoryItem) in onListItemClick method?

Comment: @Janis yes you can do it.use the getItem method of Adapter so that you will get the CategoryItem and there you can set category.is_active=true.
For example in OnListItemClick you can do the following
CategoryAdapter adapter = (CategoryAdapter )parent.getAdapter();
CategoryItem item = adapter.getItem(position);
item.is_active = true;
CategoryItem prevItem = adapter.getItem(previousposition);
prevItem = false;
previousposition = position;
i Hope this will satisfy your needs.